# How to get to an input field with the keyboard in firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard

Let's say I am doing a search in google and I want to come back to the input field to modify the search, I normally use the mouse to click, but these is a waste of time, after scrolling down, you need to backup and click.

Is there a way in firefox to focus onto input fields using the keyboard instead of the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the OS and system settings, on mac you can cycle through all fields using tab - in the [keyboard preference pane (cultofmac).](http://www.cultofmac.com/263762/get-mac-tab-every-field-web-forms-os-x-tips/)
I am not sure how/if this can be done in windows.

In any case Control-L (pc) or Command-L (mac) will always bring the omni-bar into focus and since it will remember your last search this is probably the fastest way for you to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to go to the address bar in Firefox, press Ctrl + L at any time.

If you need to go to the search box, press Ctrl + J.

A list of keyboard shortcuts can be found [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly).

Comment: Didn't know Ctrl+J works also. Been using Ctrl+K to toggle search box for years.\

Comment: I think `Ctrl+J` is for accessing downloads. (For windows)

Comment: I think it used to be the case but they changed that. You access downloads now using Ctrl + Shift + Y. 
For more: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_search

Comment: I just upgraded to Firefox 29 today. Ctrl+J is still definitely Downloads.